# JavaScript and HTML Passing ID Values when Adding NewCell

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the ID of an inputs to get its total, the ID is name "qty", this worked when I was working with input boxes. But then when I switched to tables, which cells are entered via javascript. It wouldn't work. HI have three questions

Here's my code:

my javascript:

```
 function addRow()
  {
    var table = document.getElementById("datatable"),
      newRow = table.insertRow(table.length),
      cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0),
      cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1),
      cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2),


      name = document.getElementById("form").value,
      amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;


      delete1 = delete1 = '<input type="button"  class="btn btn-danger" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"id="delete" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)">';
    cell1.innerHTML = name;
    cell2.innerHTML = amount;
    cell3.innerHTML = delete1;
  }
```

my HTML:

```
<h2>Type in Nature of Collection...</h2>

<form>  
  <input class="form-control input-lg" id="form" list="languages" placeholder="Search" type="text" required>
  <br>
  <input class="form-control input-lg" id="amount" list="languages" placeholder="Amount" type="number" required>
  <br>
  <button onclick="addRow(); return false;">Add Item</button>
</form>

<h3><fieldset disabled>
  <label>Total </label>
  <input type = "text" name = "total" id="total"><br></p>
</fieldset></h3>
```

I have two questions

How do I add an ID for every cell inserted? as you can see on my javascript, I haven't added the id yet, but so far I tried.

```
var ID = 'qty'
cell2.id = newRow.ID
```

Thinking this would match my TOTAL Javascript which is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function findTotal(){
   var arr = document.getElementByName('qty');
   var tot=0;

   for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
      if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
        tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
   }
   document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
 }
</script>
```

Which adds every amount where id is set to qty and displays it in the "total" input bat.

How do I fetch the values of all these values at once?

Thanks! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There's no need to assign a new `id` to anything; you can grab the respective cells using `document.querySelectorAll("#datatable td:nth-child(2)")`

Comment: @ChrisG  this gets the second <td> am I right? In what format does it gets the value?

Comment: @Rekt https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: This should become an answer, but not sure if it would work with the problem of the Asker, if he tries `var arr = document.querySelectorAll("#datatable td:nth-child(2)");` what do you think? Its non-live nodelist. Will `findTotal()` be able to fetch those values and evaluate them?